# Rive animation in Vue.js - Use .riv file from assets

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, rive

I followed the [official documentation](https://help.rive.app/runtimes/quick-start) to implement a Rive animation in Vue.js:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="canvas" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Rive } from "@rive-app/webgl";
export default {
  mounted() {
    new Rive({
      canvas: this.$refs.canvas,
      src: "http://localhost:8081/test.riv",
      autoplay: true,
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

This works just fine this way. When I try to replace the `src` parameter with a path to the `.riv` file in the `assets` folder the animation won't show. I already tried:

```
src: "../assets/test.riv",
src: "assets/test.riv",
src: "@/assets/test.riv",
src: require("../assets/test.riv"),
src: require("assets/test.riv"),
src: require("@/assets/test.riv"),
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your first try actually looks correct</strike>

Just realized, that this just worked due to browser caching

You can simply put all your `.riv` files into `public/assets` and reference them like `assets/your-file.riv`.

[image]

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder